# How to represent "loading" in a GUI

Tags: c#, wpf

My application takes almost 4 seconds to completely shut down after the user confirms the shutting down. I am trying to show some activity and maybe a progress to the user within those 3 seconds. So the scenario would be something similar to

> ButtonClose_Click() -> Are you sure you want to exit? -> Yes ->
>   "Closing"

I tried to just display a window (messagebox) but I am using DevExpress windows and they are either `OkCancel`, `Ok`, `YesNo` and `YesNoCancel` so basically it needs a user input to continue:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    () =>
    {
        DXMessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow,
        "Text Here..", "Title Here.. ", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Information); // Ok by Default
    });
```

This is what I have:

```
var result = DXMessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow,
    "Are you sure you want to EXIT the application?",
    "Attention", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.);

if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
{
    //         
    // I want to show or display some "loading" activity here till the below code finishes executing"
    // 

    mainViewModel.SaveDatabase(); // save database+
    mainViewModel.CaptureViewModel.cameraController.TurnCameraLights(false, false, false); // turn off some lights
    mainViewModel.CaptureViewModel.Uninitialize(); // clear stuff
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

How could I approach that?

Comment: What's wrong with the standard busy cursor?

Comment: @Cody that is a good idea but there is no mouse. It is a Touch Application and used on Tablets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple busy indicator that I've used a few times. You just need a property IsBusy in your viewmodel. Just place this over the top of the rest of your controls.

The best thing is that it won't show over your controls while you're editing in the design view!

```
        <Grid>
        <!--all of your controls-->

            <!--Loading Indicator-->
            <Border x:Name="_LoadingIndicator" Background="#AA000000">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Red" FontSize="80">Loading...</TextBlock>
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsBusy}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```

Here is what it will look like:
[image: Here is what it looks like.]

Comment: I tried that and it is fine to be used as an indication that the application is closing. But what if I have several views? I will need to add that on every xaml and viewModel right?

Comment: You will need to add it to whatever windows you want to show the "Loading..." indicator. I bet you could probably make a control that has that by default...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the WPF Toolkit Busy Indicator:

https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator&referringTitle=Home

You wrap your control with the indicator then set the bound flag to True for the duration of the long running process.

Answer (score 1):

I use the ProgressRing from MahApps.Metro.

http://mahapps.com/controls/progress-ring.html

The code is open source or you can get the binaries using Nuget.